# How to skip bios keyboard check on boot

Tags: bios

is there a way to skip keyboard check "presence" on boot ? I need to boot a P4 without keyboard. But Bios (Award 6.0g)  block the boot because it not find the keyboard... How can i do ?

Comment: Adding you motherboard make and model number to your question will give you answers more specific to your model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look for a setting called "Halt on Error" and disable it.